# あげる but in an unwelcomed manner

Tags: word-choice, giving-and-receiving

Taking an example 食べてあげる. This means to eat for someone else' sake (in favour of someone else). What if I wanted to say I am sorry for eating it, it would be wrong to say 食べてあげてごめん. Is there a word to replace あげる in this case? Something like やがって but the person doing the action is myself (first person).

Comment: Do you mean やがって (やがる)?

Comment: @broccoli facemask - cloth edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no grammar for giving negative *favor*. What you mentioned やがって (やがる) tells negative *honorific*, which is another category.

It is possible to use favor verbs ironically, but even if so, it only makes sense by pretending a good will, thus 食べてあげてごめん won't work anyway.

You can only say 食べちゃってごめん (食べてしまってごめん) which lets ～てしまう connote unexpected (and unfavorable) outcomes.